# How do I remove links from a page via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I want to write a user script for my browsers (Opera, Chromium) that removes links containing predefined keywords. For example, a link `<a href="foo">bar</a>` should simply vanish from the page when `foo` is part of the blacklist.

[How do i remove duplicate links from a page except first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975964/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-links-from-a-page-except-first) shows how to get and filter a site, but I want to do this directly via a user script. Any ideas how I would apply the filter on every page load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the *document.links* collection. If any of their *.href* properties match your blacklist, set their *style.display* property to *'none'*.

e.g.

```
function removeLinks () {
  var blackList = /foo|bar|baz/;
  var link, links = document.links;
  var i = links.length;

  while (i--) {
    link = links[i];
    if (blackList.test(link.href)) {
      link.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit

To remove duplicate links is a similar exercise. First convert the links *HTMLCollection* to a plain array, then as you iterate over them use their hrefs as create properties of an object. If the href is already a property, hide it using the above method or *link.parentNode.removeChild(link)*.

Comment: Would it be possible to remove all links on the page (instead of just the links in the blacklist)?

Comment: Sure, just remove the `if` test. If you want to remove the link node from the DOM, use `link.parentNode.removeChild(link);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XPATH](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and its [contains() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) to match the links via [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate).

[Dive Into Greasemonkey](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/) has an exampl eof [selecting and iterating over nodes using XPATH](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/patterns/match-attribute.html).

```
for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++) {
  var links = document.evaluate('//a[contains(@href, "' + blacklist[i] + '"]', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (var j = 0; j < links .snapshotLength; j++) {
    var link = links.snapshotItem(j);
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this

```
$("a[href*='" + foov + "']").css('display', 'none')
```

Comment: Just thought I would add that this can only be used with jQuery... Not native the native Javascript engine

Comment: Not to mention `hide()` would be more appropriate.